# Retrieve data from PHP file using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to set up a comments system on photos.

---

**I understand how to use $.getJSON when the array is like this:**

get.php:

```
$var = 5;
echo json_encode(array('var'=>$var));
```

main.php:

```
$.getJSON("get.php",function(data){
    number = data.var; // number = 5
});
```

But I have a more complex thing.

---

My *comments* table has these 4 columns: **id | photo_id | comment | date**

For example let's say we're trying to retrieve the comment data from the photo with

`photo_id == 1`.

We don't know how many comments there might be.

In getcomments.php:

```
$photoid = 1;

$comment = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photo_id='$photoid'");

while($commentrow = $comment->fetch_assoc()) {
    $comments[] = $commentrow;
}
```

Then you encode it:

```
echo json_encode($comments);
```

Which prints something like this (the photo has 2 comments):

```
[{"id":"1","photo_id":"1","comment":"text","date":"23858556"},{"id":"2","photo_id":"1","comment":"text","date":"23858561"}]
```

**How do I declare variables for the comments array?**

```
$.getJSON("getcomments.php",function(data){
    // how do I declare variables for the comments array, especially since you don't know how many there might be?
});
```

---

Additionally, I have two json arrays that need to be echoed within the same PHP file. i.e. `echo json_encode(array('img1'=>$img1link))` and `echo json_encode($comments);` need to be echoed within the same PHP file, but it made the code stop working altogether.

Comment: If you want to display the comments you need to loop over the array. You can use for loop or forEach function.

Comment: I think you mean `main.js:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display the comments you need to loop over the array. You can use for loop or forEach function.

```
$.getJSON("getcomments.php",function(data){
    data.forEach(function(comment) {
        $('div').append('<span>' + comment.comment + '</span>');
    });
});
```

To display two JSONs you need to combine them into one JSON object.

```
echo json_encode(array('img' => $img1link, 'comments' => $comments));
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this working. I put your code in a completely new file, added a <div></div> put the two JSONs in the same array etc.

Comment: @frosty If you put both JSONs in array as in second code, you will need to use `data.comments.forEach`

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"id":"1","photo_id":"1","comment":"text","date":"23858556"},{"id":"2","photo_id":"1","comment":"text","date":"23858561"}]
```

Using this JSON, `data` is an array and you should manage it as an array. You can loop through it using simple loops (`for`, `while`...) or using new functional methods like `forEach`, `map`, `filter`....

Please try with this example:

```
$.getJSON("getcomments.php",function(data){
    data.forEach(function(item, index, all) {
        console.log(item.comment);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an object, and push it to the array.

```
var commentsArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var objToPush = {
        id: data.id,
        comment: data.comment,
        date: data.date
    }

    commentsArr.push(objToPush);
}
```

Comment: ```data``` is an array. ```data.id``` is undefined.

Comment: btw ```commentsArr``` will be the same as ```data```... don't you think?